# Qt4: connect slot and signal from other forms

Tags: c++, qt

I have a *small* problem. I want run function in MainWindow from AnotherWindow. I can't set `connect()` for it.

```
Main class: MainWindow
Other form: AnotherWindow
Function in main class: setVariable(QString)
Function in other form: btnClicked()
```

I have now connected button signal `clicked()`:

```
// In AnotherWindow.cpp
connect(ui->btnOK, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btnOkClicked()));

// Function in same file
void interfaceWindow::btnOkClicked() {
    /* Some actions - emit signal? */
    this->close();
}
```

`btnOkClicked()` are declared as private slot.

```
// In MainWindow.cpp
void MainWindow::setVariable(QString _var) {
    this->var = _var;
}
```

`setVariable(QString)` are declared as public slot.

How I can send variable from AnotherForm (from `btnOkClicked()` function) to MainWindow (`setVariable(QString)` function) ? How and where I must send signal and make connection?

I readed about signals and slots, but my code don't work - I don't paste it here because it's terrible  :)

Any help for Qt newbie?

Comment: what exactly does doesn't work mean, doesn't work as it it doesn't compile, or doesn't work as in I tried to click the button but nothing happens

Comment: I can't compile my program with code from my mind and Google - I don't know how I can do it, too many informations for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an reference of AnotherWindow in MainWindow OR vice versa. Then you need the following things:

```
// AnotherWindow.h
signals:
    void buttonOkClickedSignal(QString var);

// AnotherWindow.cpp
void interfaceWindow::btnOkClicked() {
    emit buttonOkClickedSignal("The button got clicked!");
    this->close();
}
```

Next step varies based on whether MainWindow has reference to AnotherWindow or vice versa. You can either:

```
// AnotherWindow.cpp
connect(this, SIGNAL(buttonOkClickedSignal(QString), &mainWindow, SLOT(setVariable(QString)));
```

or:

```
// MainWindow.cpp
connect(&anotherWindow, SIGNAL(buttonOkClickedSignal(QString), this, (SLOT(setVariable(QString)));
```

If you are invoking the slot through signal it shouldn't matter whether it's private or public (see [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, Im forgot about `MainWindow *w = new MainWindow()` - reference is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but let me try.

You want to be able to fire a slot in another class. There are a few ways you can do that.

1. Declare one as a friend class to the other. Then they can see the `protected` and `private` variables/memebers
2. It is possible to make slots static so you can call them without a class object.

For example,

```
class MainWindow {
    private slot:
    void setVariable(QString);
}



class AnotherWindow {    
    friend class MainWindow;    
    MainWindow *window;

public:
    AnotherWindow() {
       connect(this, SIGNAL(fire(QString)), window, SLOT(setVariable(QString)));
    } 

signals:
    void fire(QString);
public slots:
   void onButtonClicked() {
       emit fire(QString);
   }
}
```

The previous is pseudocode so don't expect it to compile. I *think* this is what you want. Basically since your slot is private on `MainWindow` you need to make it a friend. To connect, it needs to be a member. Then when the `onButtonClicked` slot is evoked, then it `fire()`s the `setVarialbe()` slot.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation, you don't need to make MainWindow a friend class of AnotherWindow. The Qt Signal/Slot mechanism works even if the slot is private.
You could also make the signal or the slot public, which I think could express better the intent

Comment: @DanielCastro I think the OP meant that he wanted to connect a class signal to another class's private slot. I don't think you can do this without having a friend class. A private slot is like a private member function. It would be easier for the OP to make the slot public, but I wrote it like this because the original question had the slot as private.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that. If that's possible, however, what is the point of having scoped slots? Why aren't they all globally visible like signals?

Comment: You make the slot private so, like normal methods, can't be called _directly_ where it is not accessible. You can't, for example, use `a.mySlot()` inside main in the last example, because mySlot is a private method. But Qt can always access your slots. Keep in mind that the SLOT macro only converts mySlot() into a string like "2mySlot()"

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for your another window:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
   public:

MyWidget(QWidget * parent = 0)
{
    okBtn = new QPushButton ("I am Ok!");
    MyData = "";
    connect(okBtn ,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(OnOk()));

}
~MyWidget();

private:
  QString MyData;
QPushButton * okBtn;
  //something that modify string MyData
 signals:

    void MyDataSignal(QString);
//Internal slot that emits signal with proper data
private slots:
    void OnOk()
    {
        if(MyData!="")
        {
            emit MyDataSignal(MyData);
        }
    }

};
```

Now in MainWindow create an object of MyWidget (suppose myWid)and connect it to slot

```
connect(myWid, SIGNAL(MyDataSignal(QString)),this,SLOT(OnMyWidOkClicked(QString)));
```

the signal will pass string to slot.

While making signals and slots keep in mind following points:

1. To connect a signal to a slot (or to another signal), they must have the same parameter
2. Parameters should be in the same order in both signal and slot.
3. if a signal has more parameters than the slot it is connected to, the additional parameters are simply ignored but opposite is not possible.
4. If you will connect a signal that have unmatched parameters to slot then no compile time error will occur but at run time command window will show a warning that signal/slot/connection does not exist.